# Building a Wheel of Fortune game and I'm trying to get the keypress event to detect a letter in the random word array

Tags: javascript, onclick, event-handling

I'm working on a Wheel of Fortune game where a random word is chosen from an array. I created a function below my game function to detect the key pressed from a list of letters displayed on screen from A-Z. My problem is that I can't get the game to detect the key pressed until the randomWord() function is fired after the playGame() button is pressed. I'm trying to get the letter pressed by the user in the buttonPress() function to match a letter in the wordChoice.length loop and display on the screen where the _ would be and then rule out the letter after it's been used. I tried creating the letterClicked variable and making it global so that my playGame() function can access it but I'm not having any luck matching the letter selected by the user and the letter in the display box above the play button. What am I doing wrong here? I tried console logging throughout the randomWord() function but the keypress is only being detected after you click play and essentially reset the game. Here is my code below. Thanks for your help!

```
<DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Wheel of Fortune</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">

    </head>
    <body>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="header">
                <p class="welcome">Welcome to Wheel of Fortune!</p>
                <!-- The letters will be tied to the number of letters in the random array -->
                <p class="letters">There are <span id="numbers">0</span> letters in this word</p>
                <!-- The user will be given a number of choices and with each wrong choice, they lose a turn -->
                <p class="lives">You have <span id="guesses">0</span> guesses left</p>

                <span id="words"></span><br>

                <button id="play" onclick="playGame()">Play</button>

            </div>
            <div id="alphabet" onclick="buttonPress(event)">
                <button>A</button>
                <button>B</button>
                <button>C</button>
                <button>D</button>
                <button>E</button>
                <button>F</button>
                <button>G</button>
                <button>H</button>
                <button>I</button>
                <button>J</button>
                <button>K</button>
                <button>L</button>
                <button>M</button>
                <br>
                <button>N</button>
                <button>O</button>
                <button>P</button>
                <button>Q</button>
                <button>R</button>
                <button>S</button>
                <button>T</button>
                <button>U</button>
                <button>V</button>
                <button>W</button>
                <button>X</button>
                <button>Y</button>
                <button>Z</button>
            </div>

            <span id="your-guess">You guessed </span>
        </div>

        <script src="main.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>

    body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1000px;
    font-size: 20px;
    background: url("http://res.cloudinary.com/angelrodriguez/image/upload/c_crop,h_624/v1534810805/wheeloffortune.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    color: white;
}

#header {
    margin: 20px;
}

#alphabet {
    margin: 20px;
}

button {
    border: 2px solid blue;
    font-size: 20px;
}

#words {
    font-size: 30px;
    margin: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 20px;
}

#play {
    margin: 20px;
}




// 3. Quit the game if the player wants to.
// 5. Keep track of letters the player has guessed.
// 6. Show the player their progress.
// 7. Finish when the player has guessed the word.

// Create global variables
let gameOver = false;
var guessesLeft = 6;
var letterClicked;
var wordArray = ["JAVASCRIPT", "ARRAYS", "FUNCTIONS", "HOISTING", "RECURSION", "EVENTS", "KEYUP", "TERNARY"];
// 1. Pick a random word.



//Start a new game
function playGame() {
    newGame.addEventListener("click", function() {
        //fire the randomWord function to generate a new word
        randomWord();
    })
}

// Pass the letter event from buttonPress into the randomWord function
function randomWord(letter) {
    var answerList = [];
    // console.log(answerList);
    // letterGuessed = "";
    console.log(letterClicked);
    var wordChoice = wordArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * wordArray.length)];tbw

    var wordSplit = wordChoice.split('');
    // console.log(wordSplit);

    for (var i = 0; i < wordSplit.length; i++) {
        answerList[i] = "_";
    }

    // if the letter is in the word
    // Update the players progress with the guess
    for (var z = 0; z < wordChoice.length; z++) {
        if (wordChoice[z] === letterClicked) {
            letterClicked = answerList[i];
            // answerList[i].innerHTML = letterGuessed;
        }
    }

    //Display underscores on page representing each word in the random word
    wordDisplay.innerHTML = answerList;

    //Display number of letters in the random word on the page
    var remainingLetters = wordChoice.length;
    letterCount.innerHTML = "The word is " + remainingLetters + 
    " letters long";

}

// 2. Take the player’s guess.
function buttonPress(e) { 
    letterClicked = e.target.textContent;
    document.getElementById("your-guess").innerHTML = "You guessed the letter " + letterClicked;

    //fix issue with clicking divs
}


// If the player wants to quite the game {
//     Quit the game
// }


// Grab elements
var numbers = document.querySelector("#numbers");
var guesses = document.querySelector("#guesses");
var wordDisplay = document.querySelector("#words");
var letterCount = document.querySelector(".letters");
var newGame = document.querySelector("#play");
var letterBoxes = document.querySelector("#alphabet");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a letter in `buttonPress` you are able to use `e.toElement.textContent`.

I did some solution, but it's not a great example, i think.

```js
let words = [ "TERNARY"], guessesLeft, chosenWord;

let getRandomWord = words => {
  return words[Math.floor(Math.random()*words.length)];
}, updateGuesses = count => {
  guesses.innerText = count;
  guessesLeft = count;
}, updateWords = word => {
   document.getElementById('words').innerHTML = word; 
}, hideAlphabet = () => alphabet.style.display = 'none',
   setGameStatus = status => document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = status;

play.addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.target.style.display = 'none'; // hide when game started.
  alphabet.style.display = 'block';
  chosenWord = getRandomWord(words);
  updateGuesses(chosenWord.length);
  updateWords(String("*").repeat(chosenWord.length))
});

alphabet.addEventListener('click', e => {
  let letter = e.toElement.textContent;
  
  e.toElement.disabled = true;
  
  if (!new RegExp(letter).test(chosenWord)) {
     updateGuesses(guessesLeft -1);
  } else {
     let newString = document.getElementById('words').innerHTML.split(''), indexesOfALetter = [];
     
     for(let i = 0; i < chosenWord.length; i += 1) // here for is a fastest way. 
         if (chosenWord[i] === letter) indexesOfALetter.push(i);
     
     indexesOfALetter.forEach(i => newString[i] = letter); 
     
     updateWords(newString.join(''));
  }
  
  if (!/\*/.test(document.getElementById('words').innerHTML)) {
     hideAlphabet();
     setGameStatus("Congratulations! You won that game");
  }
  
  if (guessesLeft < 1) {
    hideAlphabet();
    setGameStatus("Unfortunately, you lost the game ;(");
    updateWords(chosenWord);
  }
  
});
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1000px;
    font-size: 20px;
   
    color: black;
}

#header {
    margin: 20px;
}

#alphabet {
    display: none;
    margin: 20px;
}

button {
    border: 2px solid blue;
    font-size: 20px;
}

#words {
    font-size: 30px;
    margin: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 20px;
}

#play {
    margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        <p class="welcome">Welcome to Wheel of Fortune!</p>
        <!-- The user will be given a number of choices and with each wrong choice, they lose a turn -->
        <p class="lives">You have <span id="guesses">0</span> guesses left</p>

        <span id="words"></span><br>

        <button id="play">Play</button>

    </div>
    <div id="alphabet">
        <button>A</button>
        <button>B</button>
        <button>C</button>
        <button>D</button>
        <button>E</button>
        <button>F</button>
        <button>G</button>
        <button>H</button>
        <button>I</button>
        <button>J</button>
        <button>K</button>
        <button>L</button>
        <button>M</button>
        <br>
        <button>N</button>
        <button>O</button>
        <button>P</button>
        <button>Q</button>
        <button>R</button>
        <button>S</button>
        <button>T</button>
        <button>U</button>
        <button>V</button>
        <button>W</button>
        <button>X</button>
        <button>Y</button>
        <button>Z</button>
    </div>

    <span id="status"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried adding e.toElement.textContent that but it's just displaying that I clicked the play button.

Comment: Thanks ya.ymer. It does work but the code is a little advanced for me so I'll try to make sense of it. I really just wanted to use the code I have now to get to the step where I get the letters the user clicks to display when the user guesses the right answer. This is for a class project and I don't want to copy the entire thing, otherwise I won't learn on my own. I do appreciate your help though, you put that together so fast!

Comment: If you have some questions, i'm glad to answer. Have a nice day!

Comment: yes I’m trying to figure out how to get my code to display the matches in the _ on the page. Nothing more than that. I see you did it with your code in ES6 but I’m not understanding what’s going on there.

Comment: You're need to find every letter in the word - i've used `for` for that. Then you're need to get every index from array which created in previous step. I've used `forEach` for that. For minify that part of code i've used the [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) - it's not different between simple `function` here, but it's using less code. We're getting numbers (it's indexes from `chosenWord`) and replacing symbols in hidden word with these indexes to clicked letter.

Comment: Okay, I'll implement that into the code I have. Thank you!

Comment: I forgot: before that i've checked is word contains chosen letter. You can read about used functions here: [`RegEx`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp), [`.test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)